# How to match two documents with different schemas?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, data-analysis

I have two data indices in Elasticsearch where I have stored documents with attributes that can be different like in products. Products from one website in one index and another website in another. These products can have different attributes and names(like size, weight,length vs measurement) What is the best way to match say product from database 1 to a product in database 2 using elasticsearch queries?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what you mean by match. Are you just trying to query something across both indices? If so you can specify more then one index/type in the URL using commas

ie. GET index1,index2/type1,type2/_search ....

You would then just do a normal query. If you do a multimatch query you can simply put in all the fields you want to search across in all the indices/types and elastic search will take care of only searching in fields that exist for a specific index/type.